# Complex integral using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following complex integral:

$$\int_{|w|=1} \frac{e^w}{w-z}dz$$ for $|z|>1$ and $|z|<1$.

My attempt: $f(z)= \frac{e^w}{w-z}$ is holomorphic (in $|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$), and $|w|=1$ is a circle (therefore a closed path), then by Cauchy's Theorem, the integral equals zero.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: The integration should probably be with respect to $w$, not with respect to $z$, and you should consider $f(w)= \frac{e^w}{w-z}$ for fixed parameter $z$.

Comment: @MartinR I thought so too, but no

Comment: Then what does $\int_{|w|=1} \frac{e^w}{w-z}dz$ even mean, if $z$  is given with $|z| < 1$ or $|z|> 1$ ?

Comment: @MartinR That's what I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|z|<1$ the answer is $2\pi ie^{z}$ by Cauchy's Integral Formula.

For $|z|>1$ your conclusion is correct, but your argument is not. Cauchy's Theorem is not applicable to $\{|z|>1\}$ because this is not a simply connected region. However, we can just apply Cauchy's Thereom to a  ball slightly larger than the unit disk (which excludes $z$).

Comment: Thanks! For case $|z|<1$ I'm not sure how this is the result, and how can you apply the Cauchy's Integral Formula if the integral is for $dz$.

Comment: $f(z)=\frac 1 {2\pi i} \int_C \frac {f(w)} {w-z}dw$.  Take $f(w)=e^{w}$. @Ludwig